# Arrange query output by sheet name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

thanks in advance.

Is there a way to arrange my multiple sheets query output by sheets name? so there is a separation between the two when they stack on top of each other?

```
=QUERY({orange!A2:I24;'apple'!A2:I26},"select Col1,Col2 where Col1 !='' ",1)
```

cheers to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`={query({orange!A2:I24},"select Col1,Col2, 'orange' where Col1 !='' ",1);
query({'apple'!A2:I26},"select Col1,Col2, 'apple' where Col1 !='' ",1)}`

The only way is to hardcode sheet names. There's no formula to get sheet names automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some specific data marker to differentiate between sheets, I don't think it's possible. But you may well use two queries like,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY({orange!A2:I24},"select Col1,Col2 where Col1 !='' ",1);QUERY({'apple'!A2:I26},"select Col1,Col2 where Col1 !='' ",1)})
```

If you have a specific data marker,

```
=QUERY({orange!A2:I24;'apple'!A2:I26},"select Col1,Col2 where Col1 !='' order by Col3",1)
```

Where Col3, i.e., C column should be say,`1` in orange sheet and `2` in Apple sheet.

Comment: thank you my friend didn't know its possible to make an array like this cheers